# Assembly to high-level language conversion

Tags: delphi, assembly, reverse-engineering

Is there any way to convert assembly language to some high-level language?
I am trying to make linux port of application for retrieving school marks. Application downloads file from server and then decrypts it somehow. It is written in delphi but after decompilation i got an assembly language. Assembly language is totally unknown to me.
Here is the procedure that i think it is responsible for decription: https://gist.github.com/1240056
If there is any other way how to find out used algorithm i would be very thankful to you.

Comment: Do you really think that you'll get some answer about how to get a source code after a decompilation ? It's totally illegal and (hopefully) impossible.

Comment: @az01 article 6 of 91/250/EEC: http://eur-lex.europa.eu/LexUriServ/LexUriServ.do?uri=CELEX:31991L0250:EN:HTML

Comment: @az01, thats not true, it is not **totally** illegal.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code you supplied is definitively not doing any decryption by itself, IMHO.

This sounds like some high-level UI stuff and getting some content from a text file retrieved from internet, and refresh the UI. There is no decryption loop inside.

The decryption is certainly some of the internal calls, which reads some password from the UI, then make calls to retrieve some data from Internet, read the content, and update the UI. Check 0048E004 method for instance (or one other `call` around).

Search for such a pattern:

```
@loop:
  mov al,[esi]
  xor al,...
  mov [edi],al
  inc esi
  inc edi
  dec ecx
  jnz @loop
```

Or

```
@loop:
  xor [edx],...
  inc edx
  dec ecx
  jnz @loop
```

Then maybe a call to `LStrCmp` for instance (it is a string comparison).

Of course, registers esi/edi/ecx/edx may be local variables [ebp+...] or other registers. But you may recognize this pattern.

Encryption may be MUCH more difficult this this loop, but there is quite always a xor ...,... during encryption/decryption, with a loop through all bytes.

I'm not talking about `xor eax,eax` lines, which are in fact `eax := 0` but some `xor al,...` were `...` is not al.

Comment: Thanks, this was very promissing, but  only xors in that procedure (https://gist.github.com/124088) are xors of same registers, i've also checked all other files but every occurence of xor is followd by two same operands. Is there any other way?

Comment: Wrong password message is on address 0048F159 (Unit_34.pas - http://dl.dropbox.com/u/1189439/znamky.zip). Password is in field OknoRodice.eHeslo, so i think it should be in between wrong password and getting text from field (I have poor knowledge of assembly language so i am probably wrong.

Answer (score 5):

[Decompilers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decompiler) are notoriously unreliable. Too much information is lost in the compilation process to reliably convert back to source code in most cases. To have any chance at all of working you must use a decompiler which matches (ie, knows how to reverse the compilation process of) the language, OS, and ideally the compiler of the original code. But even then, the resulting output is unlikely to be any more legible than the assembly code; and decompilers which can actually make it to real, compilable code are *extremely* rare.

I would recommend that you learn assembly code and try to reverse-engineer it that way, or just run this program in wine.

Comment: Program cannot be run in wine. Probably there is some missing dependency.
I have used delphi decompiler (http://kpnc.org/idr32/en/).
Another reason is i wan't to run it on my android phone.
Unfortunately i have no time to learn assembly language, i have chosen it as my schoolwork.

Comment: @JanTojnar, as that site says, the 'decompiler' isn't yet actually capable of decompiling. It's an interactive disassembler with features to make manual analysis easier. But you need to know assembly still.

Comment: It is delphi 2006 what also decompiler told me.

Comment: I will have to change my schoolwork topic then. But thank you for help anyway.

Comment: @JanTojnar, or learn assembler! :)

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps try to write some code yourself that does what you want rather than recreating code from a decompiled exe.  What you want doesn't sound all that complex so you should be able to recreate it.

If you are trying to get around encryption, decompiling is unlikely to help you.

Comment: i have string (most likely password file is encrypted with), but i don't know algorithm the file is encrypted with. I can create application with similar functionality, but first i have to decrypt the file to analyse it. I am trying to learn assembly on the fly but i am missing too many pieces of information.

Answer (score -1):

try to learn [IDA pro](http://www.hex-rays.com/idapro/idadown.htm) and [it's plugin](http://www.openrce.org/downloads/browse/IDA_Plugins).

But it wont help you to port the proggy on linux.
analize the logic, better off to do the new implementation.

Comment: IDA pro is super expensive, and they won't sell to just anyone... and you really need to know what you're doing to use it

Comment: Which plugin? As i know, only HexRays is capable to produce C (well, more or less, sometimes it fails miserably and produces very twisted logic)